# configuration of paths within gradle project

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project formatted like this

- `container/`

  - `dist/`
  - `mod1/`

    - `build.gradle`
  - `mod2/`

    - `build.gradle`
  - `mod3/`

    - `build.gradle`
  - `build.gradle`

basically a grade project with a lot of submodules.  What i am trying to do is when you run assembly on the container/build.gradle it runs the builds on all the sub projects.  That part is easy enough.  Now im trying to accomplish centralizing configuration settings and parameters across everything.

here is a snip from my container/build.gradle file

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'scala'

    jar {
        manifest.attributes provider: 'OnusPride'
    }

    property {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        archivePath = file("dist")
    }

    ext {
        springVersion = "3.2.1.RELEASE"
        springSecurityWebVersion = "3.1.3.RELEASE"
        springSecurityOauth2Version = "1.0.1.RELEASE"
        jacksonCoreVersion = "2.1.2"
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    }
}
```

I am trying to configure all the modules where when they finish doing their various assemble task, javajar, scalajar, war, etc, to put the output in the container/dist folder.  how do i do that?

also, does anyone have an example of a fairly complex, well written,  multi-module gradle project.  something a little more substantial than the hello world stuff would be very helpful.  learning groovy and gradle at the same time is a bit tough.

Comment: I notice that you are declaring both scala and java plugins this will cause your java code to be built twice.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828819/how-to-support-multiple-projects-in-multiple-languages-java-and-scala-in-gradl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have different options.
One solution might be to introduce a common task in your subproject to copy all output of tasks of type AbstractArchiveTask to the dist folder. This would look like this:

```
subprojects{
    task copyToDists(type:Copy){
         into project.rootProject.file("dists")
         from tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask)
    }
}
```

This solution has some overhead and is not considered to be best practice, as you start shuffeling stuff around within your build. A better approach would be to reconfigure the according task to create the jars, wars, zips per default in the desired folder:

```
subprojects{
    tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask){
        destinationDir = project.rootProject.file("dists")
    }
}
```

hope that helped.

cheers,
René

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I have not reached yet but I am about to face.  I was planning to create a task in the `container/build.gradle` that would find the artefacts in all its sub-projects and then copy these to the `dist` directory.